# Populate heading each row in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, for-loop

How to populate the heading first then row in JavaScript approach? ***I don't have the control of this data that's why I'm trying to figure out how.***

I have this data:

```
const list = [{
    'name': 'Display',
    'group': 'Technical details',
    'id': '60',
    'value': 'Something'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Manufacturer',
    'group': 'Manufacturer',
    'id': '58',
    'value': 'Apple'
  },
  {
    'name': 'OS',
    'group': 'Technical details',
    'id': '37',
    'value': 'Apple iOS'
  }
];
```

With the above data I want to achieve this output below:

```
<div class="heading">
    <div>Technical details</div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row grid">
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div>Display</div>
            <div>Something</div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <div>OS</div>
            <div>Apple iOS</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="heading">
    <div>Manufacturer</div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row grid">
            <div class="grid-item">
                <div>Manu</div>
                <div>Apple</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Summarize Question: **I just want to display the Heading first then the row that have the same group value.**

Here is my code that needs help:

```
function groupBy(collection, property) {
  var i = 0, val, index,
    values = [], result = [];
  for (; i < collection.length; i++) {
    val = collection[i][property];
    index = values.indexOf(val);
    if (index > -1) {
      result[index].push(collection[i]);
    }
    else {
      values.push(val);
      result.push([collection[i]]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var obj = groupBy(list, "group");
```

Comment: Do you have control over the data format contained in `list`? It would be better to change that data structure to be more suitable to your needs. Also, please add the JS code you've written in to the question so that we can help you debug it. Remember that SO is not here to write code for you.

Comment: I already update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you're trying to do is group your data by `group` property, and then form some HTML out of it.

Grouping is easy, then just use whatever language you're comfortable with to build the html:

```js
const list = [{
    'name': 'Display',
    'group': 'Technical details',
    'id': '60',
    'value': 'Something'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Manufacturer',
    'group': 'Manufacturer',
    'id': '58',
    'value': 'Apple'
  },
  {
    'name': 'OS',
    'group': 'Technical details',
    'id': '37',
    'value': 'Apple iOS'
  }
];

const grouped = list.reduce( (acc,i) => ({
  ...acc,
  [i.group]: (acc[i.group] ? [...acc[i.group], i] : [i])
}),{})

Object.entries(grouped).forEach( ([heading,values]) => {
  console.log(heading)
  values.forEach( ({name,value}) => {
    console.log("\t",name,"=",value)
  })
})
```

Comment: Perfect solution, this is highly appreciated got your idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This solution relies on **a `makeGroups` function to restructure the original list** into an object that better resembles the final HTML structure, and **a `createHeading` function to create a tree of divs** (for each group) with the desired classes and text contents.

(See the in-code comments for further explanation.)

```js
const
  mainContainer = document.getElementById("main-container"), // Accesses DOM
  list = getList(), // Gets original list
  groups = makeGroups(list), // Restructers list into groups obj
  groupNames = Object.keys(groups); // Gets array of names

// Makes a ".heading" div for each group and adds it to the DOM
for(let name of groupNames){
  const members = groups[name];
  const headingDiv = createHeading(name, members);
  mainContainer.appendChild(headingDiv);
}


// Builds a div w/ the class "heading", with all its contents
function createHeading(headingName, members){

  // Makes all divs except those for individual member items
  const
    headingDiv = createDiv("", "heading"),
    headingNameDiv = createDiv(headingName),
    containerDiv = createDiv("", "container"),
    rowDiv = createDiv("", "row", "grid");
  headingNameDiv.style.fontWeight = "bold"; // Formats snippet output
  headingDiv.appendChild(headingNameDiv)

  // Makes divs for individual member items and appends them to row
  for(let member of members){
    const itemDiv = createDiv("", "grid-item");
    itemDiv.appendChild(createDiv(member.name));
    itemDiv.appendChild(createDiv(member.value));
    rowDiv.appendChild(itemDiv);
  }
  // Appends everything into the heading div, and returns it
  containerDiv.appendChild(rowDiv);
  headingDiv.appendChild(containerDiv);
  return headingDiv;
}

// Makes an obj where keys are group names, values are memeber objs
function makeGroups(list){
  const groups = {};
  list.forEach(entry => {
    const {group, name, value} = entry;
    if(!groups[group]){ groups[group] = []; }
    groups[group].push({name, value});
  });
  return groups;
}

// Makes a div with optional textContent and any number of classes
function createDiv(content, ...classes){
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.textContent = content || "";
  for(let name of classes){
    div.classList.add(name);
  }
  return div;
}

// Gets the original list
function getList(){
  const list = [
    {
      'name': 'Display', // Grid-item 1
      'group': 'Technical details', // Heading
      'id': '60',
      'value': 'Something' // Grid-item 2
    },
    {
      'name': 'Manufacturer',
      'group': 'Manufacturer',
      'id': '58',
      'value': 'Apple'
    },
    {
      'name': 'OS',
      'group': 'Technical details',
      'id': '37',
      'value': 'Apple iOS'
    }
  ];
  return list;
}
```

```css
.heading{margin-top: 1em; }
.grid-item{ width: 15ch; border: 1px solid lightgrey; }
```

```html
<div id="main-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const list = [{
    'name': 'Display',
    'group': 'Technical details',
    'id': '60',
    'value': 'Something'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Manufacturer',
    'group': 'Manufacturer',
    'id': '58',
    'value': 'Apple'
  },
  {
    'name': 'OS',
    'group': 'Technical details',
    'id': '37',
    'value': 'Apple iOS'
  }
];

const groupBy = (field, list) => 
  list.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const { group } = cur
    if (group in acc) acc[group].push(cur)
    else acc[group] = [cur]
    return acc
  }, {})

const App = () => <div>
  {Object.entries(groupBy('group', list)).map(([group, items]) =>
    <div className="heading">
      <div>{ group }</div>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row grid">
        {items.map(({ name, value }) => 
          <div className="grid-item">
            <div>{name}</div>
            <div>{value}</div>
          </div>)}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )}
</div>

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,app)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id=app>
```

Comment: How this solution works in plain JavaScript?

Comment: it's very annoying to do it in plain JS. You'd have to keep using createElement() and appendChild() to manually create your elements, and use innerText for inserting text, then append everything to the DOM.

Comment: It's generally considered less helpful to an OP to include libraries or frameworks that were not part of their question. (People do this with jQuery a lot, and then the OP has to ask "Okay, but how can I do it without jQuery?".)

Comment: Absolutely agree with @Cat - however in this case the questions _was_ tagged jQuery so if you're going to include any framework in your answer it should be that one!

Comment: @Jamiec Totally -- jQuery was just an example, but thanks for pointing out that jQuery itself is welcome in answers to this particular question.